# Select every row after a blank row

Tags: sql, sql-server

After using `STRING_SPLIT` to the data in a column, I have a bunch of rows that are blank and other rows that I do not need. All the rows I need are directly under a blank row.

Is there some query that can select all the rows that come after a blank row and delete the rest of the rows?

This is the query that I have so far:

```
select value
from catalog
     cross apply string_split(path, '/')
```

[My results are in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuvlh.png), but I want the results to be (for this screenshot):

```
'HQF', 'Insurance', 'Insurance', 'Insurance', 'Insurance'...
```

Comment: Would you like to share your code, sample data, result and expected result?

Comment: Add a where clause to the select? `Where column is not null or column <> ''`?

Comment: @FerdinandGaspar I've added all of it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @matt it woudln't I missed `and other rows that I do not need`

Comment: If performance is a concern you may want to look at: https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/t-sql-queries/string-split  which basically says... use what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little concerned about the order since order isn't guaranteed... will row_number sequentially number correctly?

but here's a shot:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT value, row_number() over (order by (Select NULL)) RN
             FROM  catalog
             CROSS APPLY string_split(path, '/'))

SELECT B.*
FROM CTE A
INNER JOIN CTE  B
  on A.RN+1 = B.RN
WHERE (A.value is null or A.value = '')
  and B.value is not null 
  and b.value <> ''
```

Basically have a set of data all spaces w/ row numbers and a set of data w/ no spaces.. and join all rows to the next row only returning those where a space exists in first and data in 2nd.

Comment: I would of done this approach as well, but asked if there was an identity key instead of rownumber

Comment: @xQbert I had the same concern/curiosity of how would you maintain row_order position when splitting string.  I too wonder if ROW_NUMBER would work here or not let me know what you find out as I am curious.

Comment: Hate to be that guy again, but now there's this message:

"Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions"

Comment: Not a problem Check Matt's answer.  Instead of order by null maybe order by 1 ... or  I can't get String_Spilt to work on rextester (version Sql Server 2014 Express Edition) where I have SQL Server available.

Comment: and that's becuase it's available in 2016...  so I cna't verify my answr :(

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Catalog AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), StringToSplit VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Catalog (StringToSplit) VALUES ('A//B/C/D'),('1//2//3'),('/1/2')

CREATE TABLE #StringSplitResult (
    OrdinalID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,Id INT
    ,String VARCHAR(100)
)


INSERT INTO #StringSplitResult(Id,String)
SELECT Id, ss.value
FROM
    @Catalog c
    CROSS APPLY string_spilt(c.StringToSplit,'/') ss

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,RowBeforeString = LAG(String) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY OrdinalId)
    FROM
       #StringSplitResult
)

SELECT *
fROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowBeforeString = ''
```

I had the same concern as XQbert as far as Order of the rows after using `string_spilt`.  I decided to use a temp table to combat that by using a ID.  Here is an example using `LAG()` across multiple strings and where a string might have multiple blank rows/lines in it.

Comment: that is ***SOME*** of the same concern :P  though how is the insert guaranteed to be in the right order? same problem; I would think especially if somehow this went to multiple threads.

Comment: @xQbert Agreed, I just thought it would be more guaranteed to be directly dumped to memory in the way it comes out of the function because ROW_NUMBER() would have an effect of re-ordering results by the ORDER BY clause.  Seems to me MS should have added a second ordinal row number with the string_spilt function but I don't see one in documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: you know if we used a recursive cte to handle the split instead and applied our own numbering logic I don't think it would be a problem then.  Sadly we have to avoid the embedded function since we don't know about the order.  The april 2 2017 comment has the same question we do.  (SteveAQ)

Comment: @xQbert, good point :)  I like the xml split string method myself which I know using the temp table id method will maintain correct order. but recursive we would control and sometimes that is better :)